# Plotting markers on a datetime graph using Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

First of all, I have 2 data frames below:

```
import pandas as pd
            
df1= {
    'date' : [
        '2019-03-25 19:56:29.332874+00:00',
        '2019-03-25 20:39:55.958678+00:00',
        '2019-03-25 20:40:38.057880+00:00'
    ],
    'status' : ['buy', 'sell' ,'buy'],
    'price' : ['15', '17' ,'16'],
}
df2= {
    'date' : [
        '2019-03-25 19:00:00',
        '2019-03-25 19:30:00',
        '2019-03-25 20:00:00',
        '2019-03-25 20:30:00',
        '2019-03-25 21:00:00'
    ],
    'price' : ['13', '12' ,'16', '14', '18']
}
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df1 ['date'] = df1 ['date'].astype('datetime64')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df2['date'] = df2['date'].astype('datetime64')
```

I want to draw a line graph with `df2` and mark the `df1` on top of the `df2` graph based on its date and price. I can simply use this line of code to draw the line graph.

```
plt.plot(df2,'b-')
```

Now, how can I mark the price of `df1` on top of the graph above?
I don't mind to use either seaborn, matplotlib, or any other.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df2.date, df2.price, 'o-', label = 'df2')
plt.plot(df1.date, df1.price, 'o--', label = 'df1')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: oh. Thank you, but actually, I wanted to mark right on the blue line using the time in df1 with different color. Do I just create a new data frame with mergind df1 and df2 with the time index?